# centerVertical property getting lost after updating view

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout, I have set centerVertical for one of my linear layout which internally contains 4 listviews. It works fine. Initially each listview as one item. On click of item in any listview, I attach a new arraylist in that listview (It is like level 1 menu and level 2 menu). The code works fine but when I update any listview with level 2 arraylist, the center_Vertical property is lost for all listview and they come on top of screen.

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:splitMotionEvents="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_center1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_center2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Clear Cache"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would highly appriciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `j__m's` suggestion was partially correct:

```
Have you tried changing the heights of the ListViews to wrap_content?
```

And user `alex's` remark is correct as well:

```
wrap_content shouldn't be used on ListView.
```

Let's keep the recommendations aside for a few minutes and achieve what you are trying to:

> In my layout, I have set centerVertical for one of my linear layout
>   which internally contains 4 listviews. It works fine.

Absolutely. Say Linearlayout's initial height is A units(height is wrap_content). And RelativeLayout's height is Y units(match_parent => fills the screen). So, the following:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

aligns A/2 units of LinearLayout above line y = Y/2 and A/2 units below y = Y/2.

Since all the ListViews have height set to match_parent, their heights are equal to A units as well. This works fine for one item in each list.

Now, consider the case when one of the ListView's height grows to > Y units. In this case, LinearLayout's height also grows to Y units. And:

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

aligns Y/2 units of LinearLayout above line y = Y/2 and Y/2 units below y = Y/2.

And even the ListViews that have one item start from top. Because, their height is Y units as well.

Hope this makes sense.

The solution:

Set every ListView's height to wrap_content. Set LinearLayout's `android:gravity="center_vertical"`. Now, LinearLayout has its own y= Y/2 axis. ListViews with height equal to Y will start from the top. ListViews with height A will stay about y = Y/2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:splitMotionEvents="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_center1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_center2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Clear Cache"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Another thing:

RelativeLayouts do not have orientations.

Comment: Wonderful.. Excellent explaination. It worked like charm :). Thanks a ton for your detailed explaination.

Comment: @Sushil No problem at all. Sometimes getting a solution doesn't work as well as understanding the reason of the problem. And you are very welcome!

Comment: Yes. Knowing the reason is more important :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// you don't need to relative layout try this.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_center1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_center2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_right"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear Cache"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I replace RelativeLayout with LinearLayout, "centerVertical" doesn't even work for 1st time.